# Is there any pde whose solution evolves as a partial Fourier integral?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Is there any partial differential equation such that the its solution evolves as partial Fourier integral (continuous version of partial sum) of a function $f(x)$ which might be an condition or something of that sort? or the condition might be $F(\omega)$.

Clarification

Basically the solution should be $$u(x,\omega) = \int_0^{\omega}[A(\omega)\\cos\omega x + B(\omega)\sin\omega x]d\omega$$ where $F(\omega) = A(\omega)+iB(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of a function $f(x)$.

Here $u(.,\omega)$ evolves with $\omega$.

Some work :

It seems $$u_{xx\omega} = -\omega^2u_{\omega}$$

and unlike usual pde's the condition is at $\omega = \infty$ rather than at $\omega = 0$

Comment: I guess there isn't one

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "evolves as partial Fourier integral"? Basically, how do you envision the time parameter $t$ to interact with the partial Fourier integral?

Comment: @Willie : Have added clarification. The evolution is in frequency.

Comment: Let $F(t,x) = \rho(t) \exp(i t x)$. Then the solution to the PDE $\partial_t u = F$ with 0 initial data is exactly $$u(t,x) = \int_0^t \rho(s) \exp(i s x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @Willie Thanks.

Comment: @WillieWong : In your formula, I guess the integration is with respect to $s$ instead of $x$. Could you please add this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converted and fixed from a comment)

Let $F(t,x) = \rho(t) \exp(itx)$, then the solution to the PDE 
$$ \partial_t u = F $$
with $0$ initial data is exactly
$$ u(t,x) = \int_0^t \rho(s) \exp(isx) \mathrm{d}s. $$